# PHP combinations of letters and numbers algorithm and start from X position

Tags: php, algorithm

I've been working with this algorithm and right now as it is the output is a string like this:

> AAA AAB AAC AAD AAE AAF AAG AAH AAI AAJ AAK AAL AAM AAN AAO AAP AAQ AAR AAS AAT AAU AAV AAW AAX AAY AAZ AA0 AA1 AA2 AA3 AA4 AA5 AA6 AA7 AA8 AA9 **(END OF LOOP 1)** ABA ABB ABC ABD ABE ABF ABG ABH ABI ABJ ABK ABL ABM ABN ABO ABP ABQ ABR ABS ABT ABU ABV ABW ABX ABY ABZ **AB0** AB1 AB2 AB3 AB4 AB5 AB6 AB7 AB8 AB9 **(END OF LOOP 2)**

This works perfectly but, let's say that I want to continue from the **AB0** position. How do I continue after **X** position? I've been playing with the code trying to implement a position keeper but I run out of ideas and I'm pulling my hair out by now.

What my project does is to create a few text.txt files with all possible combinations which the code below can do, but it echoes out everything in one long string/echo, so, what I'm trying to achieve is be able to make those text.txt files into parts.

Example, need 5700 combinations (5700 loops), five text.txt of 1000 combinations and one text.txt file with the 700 combinations left. How do I continue from loop 3000 without starting from the beginning?

Here is the code I'm using:

```
<?php
ini_set('memory_limit', '3062M');
/*
Author: Luka Vidaković
Website: http://www.lvidakovic.com
Date: 21.2.2013.
*/
$charSet .= 'ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ';
$charSet .= '0123456789';

$size = strlen($charSet);
$base = array();
$counter = 0;

$maxLength = 3; // 3 for now to experiment
$baseSize = 3; // min

$loops_to_make = 1; // 0 will loop once. 1 will loop twice and so on...
$loops_done = 0;
$megavar = "";

while($baseSize <= $maxLength)
{
    if($loops_done > $loops_to_make) { break; }
    // Go through all the possible combinations of last character and output $base
    for($i = 0; $i < $size; $i++)
    {
        $base[0] = $i; //echo $i." ";
        for($j=$baseSize-1;$j>=0;$j--)
        {
            $megavar .= $charSet[$base[$j]];
        }
        $megavar .= ' ';    
    }
    // How many $base elements reached their max?
    for($i = 0; $i<$baseSize;$i++)
    {
        if($base[$i] == $size-1) { $counter++; $megavar .= "<br>|(".$j.")|"; }
        else break;
    }
    // Every array element reached max value? Expand array and set values to 0.
    if($counter == $baseSize)
    {
        // Notice <=$baseSize! Initialize 0 values to all existing array elements and ADD 1 more element with that value
        for($i=0;$i<=$baseSize;$i++)
        {
            $base[$i] = 0;
        }
        $baseSize = count($base);
    }
    // Carry one
    else
    {
        $base[$counter]++;
        for($i=0;$i<$counter;$i++) $base[$i] = 0;
    }
    $loops_done++;
    $counter=0;
}
echo $megavar; // Eventually I'll echo this into a txt file
?>
```

I'm also open to other ideas that create the same output as long is in PHP and or better.
Thanks.

Comment: It looks like you're counting in a modified version of base 36. So, I'd write a function that can convert to and from decimal. Then, to obtain the next X items in the sequence, convert your string to decimal, obtain the next X numbers using ordinary maths operations, and convert each of them back to your system.

Comment: strings will be always of length 3? I mean will this sequence finally end at `999`?

Comment: @Fallen I wrote 3 as an example, the requirements are 10 min and 10 max, Thanks.

Comment: @halfer I see what you mean, can you provide some code to start with? Thanks for the fast reply

Comment: I think now you've got some clues as to how to approach the algorithm, you could give it a go yourself. However, that would involve not peeking at the answers below... `:)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your issue is a simple case of calculating sum of given string and given positions. The only difficulty is that your numeral base is `36` and digits are custom. But that could be easily resolved with [`strtr()`](https://www.php.net/strtr) and [`base_convert()`](https://www.php.net/base_convert) combination:

```
function getSeed($string, $positions=1)
{
   $convert = array_combine(
                  array_merge(range('A', 'Z'), range('0', '9')),
                  array_merge(range('0', '9'), range('A', 'Z'))
              );
   //actually, $result can be written as one-liner
   //but that will be horrible whitespacing..
   $result  = base_convert(strtr($string, $convert), 36, 10);
   $result  = strtoupper(base_convert($result+$positions, 10, 36));
   $result  = strtr(str_pad($result, strlen($string), '0', STR_PAD_LEFT), array_flip($convert));
   return $result;
}
```

So to use it, just call:

```
$result = getSeed('AAA', 40);//ABE
```

Thus, you'll be able either generating values in loop or resuming your loop via specifying offset. Note, that I would recommend you to evaluate `$convert` outside function if you'll use it in loop. That will save unnecessary overhead.

Answer (score 1):

```
function convertNumber($number, $target_length = 10){
    $digits[]=array("A", "B", "C", "D", "E", "F", "G", "H", "I", "J", "K", "L", "M",
                    "N", "O", "P", "Q", "R", "S", "T", "U", "V", "W", "X", "Y", "Z",
                    "0", "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "7", "8", "9"); // hardcoded to make the answer clearer
    $ret = "";

    while((int)$number > 0){
        $remainder = $number % 36;
        $number    /= 36;
        $ret       .= $digits[$remainder];
    }
    while(strlen($ret) < $target_length)
        $ret .= "A"; // appending leading zero('A' is zero in this system)  to fix the size

    $ret = strrev($ret);
    return $ret;
}
```

you can run a loop on number `x` and then print `converNumber(x)`. This way no additional overhead will be needed.

**Warning:** Code not tested